Tiling trominoes to fit a $3\times 6$ grid.

A tromino is a shape made from three squares traced on gridlines. A $2 \times 3$ grid can
be tiled by trominoes in exactly three ways as shown in the picture below.
We count two tilings that are reflections of each other as different. Similarly, two
tilings that are rotations of each other are counted as different.
In how many different ways can a $3 \times 6$ grid be tiled by trominoes?

This is the picture for the question.

Since the grid we have to solve for is in form $3k$ (as with the $2\times 3$ grid stated in the question, I tried to list and find the amount of ways with $k$ increasing from $1...6$
I started with a $1\times 3$ grid, this obviously has $1$ way.
Then with a $2\times 3$ grid, there are $3$ ways as shown above.
With a $3\times 3$ grid, it starts to get quite tedious here and I do not know if there are any suitable approaches to guarantee that all possibilities are guaranteed.
However, I am thinking about a recursive strategy to find a pattern and slowly make my way up to $3\times 6$ grid.
I would appreciate it if anybody could provide a solution to this problem. Thank you very much.

"with a $2\times3$ grid, there are $6$ ways as shown above."?

@jjagmath thank you for point out that error, it is now fixed.

Look at https://oeis.org/A134438

This problem is the same as this project euler question. Using old code I found that there are $170$ ways to tile a $3\times 6$ grid and $10$ ways to tile a $3 \times 3$ grid. Of course, as this is a project euler problem, I will not share my code with you. If you are interested in efficient code that solves the problem, I'd suggest you look at the thread on project euler (you need to solve the question first (for which you can use the OEIS to cheat)).

@jjagmath I am wondering how you can calculate the answer for this question without code or calculator, just like exam requirements

Suppose you have one such tiling, and pull it apart into two halves, where trominos which lie mostly in the left 3x3 half go to the left, and trominos that are mostly in the right 3x3 go to the right half. There are a few different shapes that those halves could have, and you can count how many ways they can be filled with trominos. The hardest to count is when the two halves are exactly the 3x3 squares, and that turns out to be 10 ways, which contributes 10*10=100 tilings of the 3x6 rectangle. This works but it is easy to miss some solutions (the two "halves" need not be the same size).
